# How to monitor /dev/pts/X sessions?

Tags: linux, tty, last

I was trying to monitor some `pts` sessions I spawned using the Python `pty` module. Its a simple code like the following:

```
import pty
pty.spawn("/bin/bash")
```

I can see in the `/dev/pts/` directory that I have a new `pts` device created. However, when I see the output of `last -x` command, I cannot find any entry of this `pts`.

It's possible that I am using `last` command for the wrong purpose, but can someone explain if we can monitor the `pts` sessions like this?